# Added rows in Google Sheets missing formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have made a simple formula, based on cells in the same row, to indicate to the user that they have entered enough information—and it works as needed.

```
=IF(AND(ISTEXT(B20),ISNUMBER(C20),ISNUMBER(E20),ISTEXT(F20)),"Ok",IF(AND(ISBLANK(B20),ISBLANK(C20),ISBLANK(D20),ISBLANK(E20),ISBLANK(F20)),"","MORE INFO"))
```

However, when I click the "add more rows" button at the bottom of the sheet, the formula is not present in the new cell—but any drop down menu or validation I've used in the cells not containing the formula are present in the respective added cells of the new row. Any ideas why just the formula is missing?

Comment: Also, the conditional formatting is kept in the added cell - just not the formula

Answer (score 1):

This is  with the assumption my data starts at row 2 (under my headers)

```
=arrayformula(if(istext(B2:B)*n(C2:C)*n(E2:E)*istext(F2:F),"Ok",if(len(B2:B)+len(C2:C)+len(D2:D)+len(E2:E)+len(F2:F),"MORE INFO",)))
```

Credit: GimelG from Google Docs Help Forum.

Answer (score -1):

Simply copy the formula. To save space and improve processing speed, in Google Sheets, you have limited rows at the beginning, but more could be added on if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean...... If I copy and paste, yes it works. But I want it to automatically add the formula when the Add Row button is pressed as the amount of rows required will be changed by the user (and not me the owner of the sheet).